# Plotting from MATLAB with matfig2pgf: some plots do not show up in the pdf

Tags: matlab

I am ploting from Matlab with `matfig2pgf`. I plot two lines put only part of them show up in the .pdf, once it's compiled:

```matlab
dat1= [-500:1000, rand(1501,1}]
dat2= [-500:1000, cos(rand(1501,1})]

XLimm=[100 300];
figure(4345)
plot(dat1(:,1),dat1(:,2),'Color',[0 1 0],'Linestyle','-','Linewidth',1.5)
plot(dat2(:,1),dat2(:,2),'Color',[1 0 0],'Linestyle',':','Linewidth',1.5)
set(gca,'XLim',XLimm)
%...
matfig2pgf('filename', 'TeXfig/figure.pgf', 'fignr', 4345,'converttexttolatex',0);
```

The plot in the .pdf does not show all the lines (once compiled), actually, they are missing in the .pgf already!

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try not to plot *much* more points than what is saved to .pgf afterwards if using `matfig2pgf`.

For instance, index the point you are going to plot:

```
i_plot= logical((dat1(:,1)>=XLimm(1)).*(dat1(:,1)<=XLimm(2)))
plot(dat1(i_plot,1),dat1(plot,2),'Color',[0 1 0],'Linestyle','-','Linewidth',1.5)
```

Cheers,
Jonas

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd recommend you to use matlab2tikz instead of matfig2pgf (which matlab2tikz is based on).

See https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz, or http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022